# 404 error calling rest method on wcf hosted in IIS6

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-6

I'm runn8ing out of options on this one - having tried all the possible solutions I've found in this forum and others.

I've created a RESTful webservice using WCF, in C# dot net 4 and I've set it up on a Windows2003 box to be hosted as a service in IIS6. It previously worked fine on my local dev machine

When I run the service file eg. http://localhost/TestRestService/Service1.svc/, I get a 200 response back from the server, and "end point not found" message from the service (which is expected.  But when I run the method on the service, eg: http://localhost/TestRestService/Service1.svc/GetSuburbStateRecords?postcode=4000, I get a 404 error from the server, and the message titled "Request error: The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details".

BTW, I've allowed all relevant web service extensions.

Any ideas?
TIA
Michael

Comment: Could you post your config and the contract for your service?